# Type Error: List indices must be integers, not tuples

Tags: python

I have to create a graph using an Adjacency List or Matrix, and include functions to add a Vertex and an Edge. I keep getting different errors in the same line however. 
I get this error in

```
def getConnection(self):
    return self.Edge[()]
```

That's just what I get with it displayed like that. I've tried

```
return self.Edge()
```

and

```
return self.Edge[]
```

but i'm getting other type errors instead. What do I need to change here?

```
#Graph for Reference and use in BFS and DFS
graph = {'0': ['2'],
         '1': ['3', '0'],
         '2': ['3', '4'],
         '3': ['2', '4', '5'],
         '4': ['5', '6'],
         '5': ['6', '7'],
         '6': ['7', '8'],
         '7': ['8', '9'],
         '8': ['9', '0'],
         '9': ['0', '5'] }

class Vertex:

    def __init__(self, Label, Edge):
        self.Label = 0
        self.Edge = []

    def AddNeighbour(self, neighbour, weight=0):
        self.Connection[neighbour] = weight

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.Label) + ' connected to: ' + str([i.Label for i in self.Edge])

    def getConnection(self):
        return self.Edge[()]

    def getLabel(self):
        return self.Label

class Graph:
    def __init__(self):
        self.VertexList = {}
        self.NumVertices = 0

    def AddVertex(self, Label):
        self.NumVertices = self.NumVertices + 1
        NewVertex = Vertex(Label, None)
        self.VertexList[Label] = NewVertex
        return NewVertex

    def GetVertex(self,n):
        if n in self.VertexList:
            return self.VertexList[n]
        else:
            return None

    def __contains__(self,n):
        return n in self.VertexList

    def AddNeighbour(self, neighbour, weight=0):
        self.Connection[neighbour] = weight

    def AddEdge(self,f,t,cost=0):
        if f not in self.VertexList:
            NewVertex = self.AddVertex(f)
        if t not in self.VertexList:
            NewVertex = self.AddVertex(t)


    def GetVertices(self):
        return self.VertexList.Label()

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.VertexList.values())

g = Graph()
for i in range(10):
    g.AddVertex(i)

g.VertexList

g.AddEdge(0,2,0)
g.AddEdge(0,3,0)
g.AddEdge(1,3,0)
g.AddEdge(1,0,0)
g.AddEdge(2,3,0)
g.AddEdge(2,4,0)
g.AddEdge(3,2,0)
g.AddEdge(3,4,0)
g.AddEdge(3,5,0)
g.AddEdge(4,5,0)
g.AddEdge(4,6,0)
g.AddEdge(5,6,0)
g.AddEdge(5,7,0)
g.AddEdge(6,7,0)
g.AddEdge(6,8,0)
g.AddEdge(7,8,0)
g.AddEdge(7,9,0)
g.AddEdge(8,9,0)
g.AddEdge(8,0,0)
g.AddEdge(9,0,0)
g.AddEdge(9,5,0)

for v in g:
    for w in v.getConnection():
        print("( %s , %s )" % (v.getLabel(), w.getLabel()))
```

Comment: I think you just want ``return self.Edge``.

Comment: What did you intend to get back from a list by calling [()]?  If you wanted to create a new duplicate list, return list(self.Edge) or return self.Edge[:] Since you don't modify it, jasonharper's is better. Unrelated note -- Graph.AddEdge does not actually add an edge.

Comment: Thanks guys. And I know that that isn't the only problem with this graph, it's just the one I'm stuck on for now. I've never done this before so I'm struggling a bit with it. Do you know what I would need to do to get Graph.AddEdge to actually add a node? I deleted the line i think I needed by accident and now I can't for the life of me remember it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you define Edge as a list, you can return:

- the list itself: `return self.Edge`
- a copy of the list: `return self.Edge[:]`
- an element of the list: `return self.Edge[i]`
- a slice of the list: `return self.Edge[i:j]`

Of course, in the last two cases, you have to define and initialize i and j respectively.  If not used, they would mean beginning and end of the list respectively (ie `self.Egde[:j]` would return you a list of all elements up to position j).  Many variations are possible on that topic: the last element(s), one element on two,...